# Corona SDK. Save an image that is bigger than the screen

Tags: iphone, coronasdk, photo-gallery, image-capture

When saving a photo in Corona SDK. Regardless of the method used it seems no to be possible to capture any offscreen contents. For instance a 500x500 image displayed on a 320x480 device would be cropped at 320x480 when saved with display.save()

Is there a workaround for this? Is it possible to.

1. Save offscreen content?
2. Save or use an image directly from the device photo library?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think there is a way to capture offscreen content using Corona. Maybe there is a workaround to your whole problem if you give us more details.
2. Have you looked at the [media.show](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/show.html) function. With this you can load images from the photo library or the camera. It has option to either show the image directly on the screen or just save it to the sandbox.

Comment: Save the photo library to a file will work. Is that a new feature in media.show? I didn't know it was possible. thx

Comment: Yes, I think it is quite new actually. More and more features are added to Corona every release. You can follow their [blog](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/) to stay updated. Hopefully in a near future Corona will be a good alternative to use for most kind of apps.